# Спавн объекта unity в canvas

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой, есть такой скрипт, который заменяет объект другим объектом с иерархии.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class replace : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject object;
    public Transform TwoObject;
    public void rep()
    {
        var posForObject = object.transform.position;
        Destroy(floppa);
        var spawn = Instantiate(TwoObject, posForObject, Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
    }
}
```

Мне надо, чтобы объект спавнился *в директории canvas'а*! Как это можно осуществить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//создаем
var spawn = Instantiate(TwoObject, posForObject, Quaternion.identity);
// задаем парента
spawn.transform.SetParent(CanvasObject.transform);
```

Comment: CS0103: The name 'CanvasObject' does not exist in the current context
ошибку такую дает

Comment: как следует из названия обьекта - ты туда должен передать обьект канваса.

Comment: спасибо, а то просто тупанул